# How we can check arr and stringA are satisfied with targetString in one goal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

I have a scenario to check whether the array or a string includes one specific string.

For example, we have a returned variable which can be an array or a string. Then we need to check when it is array, it includes targetString, when it is a string, it equals to targetString

```
const returnedVariable = ['1', '2', '3'] or "1";

const targetString = "1"
```

May I please know how we can check this in one goal?

Comment: Can you add some more example inputs and expected outputs? I don't see why you wouldn't want `"123".includes(targetString)` to be `true` based on the description of the problem. Is your condition just `targetString === "1"`?

Comment: Yes, Ryan. for string I need to check stringA === targetString but for array i need to check  whether arr has stargetString using arr.includes(targetString). but i want to do these two check in one goal. The way I am using(includes method)will make some mistake when stringA is "123". As it will also return true "123".includes(targetString). Hope it makes sense to you

Comment: use an && condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a single method that has this behavior. You could make your own function to do it though. `typeof` can be used to tell whether you're checking a `string`; you could also use `Array.isArray` to tell if you're checking an `Array`.

```js
function isOneOrHasOne(thingToCheck, targetString) {
    if (typeof thingToCheck === "string") {
        return thingToCheck === targetString;
    }
    
    return thingToCheck.includes(targetString);
}

console.log(isOneOrHasOne(["1", "2", "3"], "1")); // true
console.log(isOneOrHasOne("1", "1"));             // true
console.log(isOneOrHasOne("123", "1"));           // false
```